# Playing the F major scale for kids

Tags: piano, scales

I've got a simple question here:

- How is it easier for a kid (7 years old) to play the F major scale on piano?

1-2-1-2-1-2-3-4 or 1-2-3-4-1-2-3-4, or maybe some other way?

Comment: Why not figure out which one is easier for the particular child in question?

Comment: @ToddWilcox you mean let him try both ways?

Answer (score 4):

The right way is 1-2-3-4-1-2-3-4
I believe you should get the kid used to it. 
There are very specific rules as to how play each scale in each hand, smarter people than me thought it over, and it is the best way.

Comment: Where have you found these very specific rules? And who said they're the best way?

Comment: My teacher. They are comfortable and they work. Also - professionals seems to use them naturally.

Comment: If you've got a better basis for scale fingering than 'do a 4-finger run wherever possible' let's hear it!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the ultimate aim is efficient piano playing, go for the second one.  Why learn a scale if you aren't going to use scale-type fingering?

Comment: Fingers are short and basically this scale is troublesome to play for him.

Comment: Take the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it would be best to stick with the conventional fingering.  He will only have to relearn it later on with the correct fingering if you use 1-2-1-2-1-2-3-4 now.

Comment: Why would he have to re-learn it later on? Even in exams, there is no necessity to play scales with the 'correct' fingering. And even if he did re-learn it, that would be with different sized fingers than those he uses now.

Comment: @Tim - Maybe he wouldn't need it for exams, he needs to be a good pianist. _different sized fingers_ - but the muscle memory won't disappear or change as the fingers grow.

Comment: @Stinkfoot - I don't believe that all, or even nearly all good pianists play the same things with the same fingers, and scales are no different. Often there *is* no 'correct' way. There are better and worse ways, and often several options for better. And I'm going to disagree with different fingerings for later. On guitar, for instance, I don't use the same fingering for things that I did when my fingers were smaller, and it's the same for piano (and bass, for that matter.

Comment: @Tim - Not sure what your point is. The kid should learn the right way. If and when he learns to play well and develops his own technique, so be it. Is it better to start wrong and then have fix it, or start right and then find your own way of doing certain things even though they're 'wrong'? I choose the latter.

Comment: @Stinkfoot - my point is there is more than one 'right' way to play something as basic as scales. If someone finds a different way to achieve that, it doesn't necessarily make it 'wrong'. In fact, if a different way works for someone, it most definitely isn't 'wrong'.

Comment: @Tim - It's not a law, and not being a playing pianist or a music teacher,  I really can't speak with authority, only based on what pianists here are saying by way of analogy to 'one-finger-per-fret'. But the consensus here  is _scale-type fingering - 1,2,3,4_ is the most efficient technique and is preferred by good, serious pianists, so that's called 'right' and that should be how a kid starts learning. When he learns to play well maybe his technique will change based on individual needs and preferences. (I don't play 'one-finger-per-fret' all the time either-especially on long scale basses.)

Comment: @Stinkfoot - I am both, and have been for many decades. Also I've played and taught guitar for over 50 years. I don't know everything, and certainly wouldn't pretend to. One fret per string is a fair analogy, in that it just isn't the only way to play. I watched myself at a gig last night, and found that it certainly didn't work, on bass, even on fret 12+. Whilst I understand that if there is only one best way to do something, maybe, only maybe, then that's the way, but since we're all different, anatomically at least, then other ways must be found and used. We couldn't say to Django 'sorry, .

Comment: ..if you can't play with one finger per fret, better forget it!' An extreme example, but an example nevertheless. I suppose to a degree, I'm fighting against those who are entrenched in 'there is only one way to do something (usually my way) so that's what you'll do' and can't or won't explore other avenues which may well suit the poor old student better. Rant over - for now...

Answer (score 0):

He's only really learning the fingering to play the scale. Often runs in that key in a piece won't start or finish on a note which will use the same fingering as the scale anyway. 1234,1234 is fine. He may need to push hands deeper into the keys (away from him) to reach the Bb (sometimes called A#...only kidding...).